# User Input in Two-Dimensional Array and print the sum of rows and sum of columns

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, 2d

Our assignment is to create a two-dimensional array. A 3 by 3, that computes the sum of data in row and sum of data in columns.

The output should be like this:

```
3 by 3 Array - Enter Matrix Elements.
Enter elements in pockets [0][0]: 5
Enter elements in pockets [0][1]: 9
Enter elements in pockets [0][2]: 8

Enter elements in pockets [1][0]: 3
Enter elements in pockets [1][1]: 8
Enter elements in pockets [1][2]: 2

Enter elements in pockets [2][0]: 4
Enter elements in pockets [2][1]: 3
Enter elements in pockets [2][2]: 9

Matrix is ...
5       9       8               22
3       8       2               13
4       3       9               16

12      20      19
```

But, i am having a problem when i input the values it stops after the first 3. It should be at the first row not in the columns

```
3 by 3 Array - Enter Matrix Elements.
Enter elements in pockets [0][0]: 5
Enter elements in pockets [1][0]: 9
Enter elements in pockets [2][0]: 8

Matrix is ...
5       0       0               5
9       0       0               8
8       0       0               9

22      0       0
```

This is the code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TwoDimensional_Array {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner Input  = new Scanner(System.in);

    int [][] num = new int [3][3];
    int [] sum = new int[10];
    int [] sum1 = new int [10];
    
    System.out.println("\n3 by 3 Array - Enter Matrix Elements.");

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter elements in pockets [" + i + "]["+ j + "]: ");
            num[i][j] = Input.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {    
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            sum[i] = sum[i] + num[i][j];
            sum1[i] = sum1[i] + num[j][i];
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Matrix is ...");
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(num[i][j] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println("\t" + sum[i]);
    }
    System.out.println();
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(sum1[i] + "\t");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: check the `for` loop indices involved in reading, much probably you copy&pasted the statements and forgot do change something

Comment: check `for(int j = 0; i < 3; i++)` replace `i < 3` with `j < 3`.

Comment: yup i just changed it. that's why it kept stoping btw can you help me intput values in dialogbox and also print the array in the dialog box?

Answer (score 0):

**Some matrix tips.**

**1.** A matrix definitionis `M = {m * n};`

**2.** `m` means Row, `n` means Column.

**In your problem.**

Let's create a Matrix tool to help us to fix the requirement.

```
public class SimpleMatrix {

  int[][] mat; // 2D array

  public SimpleMatrix(int[][] mat) {
      this.mat = mat;
  }

  // Matrix transpose which is to transfer the elements between rows and cols.
  public SimpleMatrix transpose() {
      int rowLen = mat.length;
      int colLen = mat[0].length;

      int[][] clones = new int[rowLen][colLen];
      for (int i = 0; i < rowLen; i++) {
          for (int j = 0; j < colLen; j++) {
              clones[j][i] = mat[i][j];
          }
      }

      mat = clones;
      return this;
  }

  public int[] getRow(int index) {
      return mat[index];
  }

  public int sumOfRow(int indexOfRow) {
      int sum = 0;
      for (int n : getRow(indexOfRow))
          sum += n;
      return sum;
  }

  public int[] getColumn(int index) {
      return transpose().getRow(index);
  }

  public int sumOfCol(int indexOfCol) {
      int sum = 0;
      for (int n : getColumn(indexOfCol))
          sum += n;
      return sum;
  }
```

In your case, we can declare the 2D nums arary like the var `mat`, and also to get the sum of int[] by using `sumOfRow()`, `sumOfCol()`.

```
public static void main(String... args) {

    int[][] mat = { 
            { 5, 9, 8 }, 
            { 3, 8, 2 }, 
            { 4, 3, 9 } };

    SimpleMatrix matrix = new SimpleMatrix(mat);
    System.out.println("sum of Row " + matrix.sumOfRow(0)); // 22
    System.out.println("sum of Col " + matrix.sumOfCol(1)); // 20
}
```

**Happy Coding !**

Comment: Hello! Thank you for this, can you help me print the matrix in joptionpane dailog box? i already did the input but i cant print the output